# UI console to browse topics on Message Hub

Tags: ibm-cloud, message-hub

I have a Message Hub instance on Bluemix, and am able to produce / consume messages off it. I was looking for a quick, reasonable way to browse topics / messages to see what's going on. Something along the lines of [kafka-topics-ui](https://github.com/landoop/kafka-topics-ui).

I installed `kafka-topics-ui` locally, but could not get it to connect to Message Hub. I used the `kafka-rest-url` value from the MessageHub credentials in the `kafka-topics-ui` configuration file (env.js), but could not figure out where to provide the API key.

Alternatively, in the Bluemix UI, under Kibana, I can see log entries for creating the topic. Unfortunately, I could not see log entries for messages in the topic (perhaps I'm looking the wrong place or have wrong filters?).

My guess is I'm missing something basic. Is there a way to either:

- configure a tool such as `kafka-topics-ui` to connect to MessageHub,
  or,
- browse topic messages easily?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Using the Kafka REST API on Bluemix](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/MessageHub/messagehub025.html#rest_using) you need an additional header in all API requests:

```
-H "X-Auth-Token: APIKEY"
```

A quick solution is to edit the [topic-ui](https://github.com/Landoop/kafka-topics-ui) code and include your token in every request. Another solution would be to use a Chrome plugin that can inject the above header. For a more formal solution, i have opened a [ticket](https://github.com/Landoop/kafka-topics-ui/issues/82) on github

Comment: Thanks, @Antonios, that worked. I had to use nginx to get around the CORS issue. I added a `proxy_set_header X-Auth-Token <token>` in nginx config, and that solved it nicely!

One other thing, I had to use `kafka-topics-ui` v 0.8.3, as the current version does not work with Bluemix.